# facebook like on a login protected page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

In my website I have facebook share/like buttons in many pages. Some pages are public and some pages are only for logged in users. The issue is, the like and share button count is not correct in logged in pages. (In the loggin protected pages, I am checking user is logged in, if not redirecting him to home page.). Instead it shows the home page count.

I validated my url in fb debug tool and the Fetched URL is showing my page and canonical url shows the home page link.

So is there any way to handle fb share/like in login protected page?

Comment: Sometimes, I understand and read `code` and sometimes I understand 'paragraphs`, here We would need some `code`

Comment: Is it that the button is set up for the site url rather then specific buttons for each page?

Comment: I have not specified the page url in the buttons. But I have correctly configured the canonical and og:url in the header meta. I think facebook internally checking the page, at that time a redirecton happens to home page.

Comment: You're redirecting the Facebook spider to your homepage because it is not authenticated - you will need to detect when it visits (either by IP or User-agent) and provide a page with only the relevant open graph headers